# document.ready sometimes doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dom

I've run into a situation where, occasionally, it seems the $(document).ready() doesn't fire on a page, which means key events don't get wired up so the page doesn't work right.  It works most of the time but every now and then it doesn't and I'm uncertain how to fix it so I'm appealing to the great pool of knowledge found here.  What can I do to ensure that my initialization function that is called when the document is ready is always executed?  Or why does document.ready not always get triggered.

I implemented a tabs control on the index.aspx page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });

</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div id="navLinks" style="display: inline-block">
    <a href="ImportAssets.aspx">Import Assets</a>
    <a href="ImportUsers.aspx">Import Users</a>
</div>
<div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="tabs">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Search.aspx">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="Users.aspx">Users</a></li>
                <li><a href="Assets.aspx">Assets</a></li>
                <li><a href="Organizations.aspx">Organizations</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Each aspx page has its own document.ready, for example, the Users.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        initializeUsersPage();
    });
</script>
```

The problem that I have is that, very occasionally, the initializeUsersPage() function doesn't get executed when transitioning from another tab to the Users tab.  Why? And how do I solve that?

Thanks in advance.\,
Darwin

Comment: Can you reproduce issue at plnkr https://plnkr.co?

Comment: `ready` means the page is "loaded" (kinda), not that the tab is active. you describe the `focus` event.

Comment: I'm not familiar with aspx much, but you say you have a document ready on the index and you have other document readies on the other pages.  I assume clicking one of those links takes you to the other pages?  When you go to those sub pages, is the logic from the index also included?  Is it like a templating thing?

Comment: Why not put a console.log inside your `.ready()`, then you can determine whether `.ready()` or `initializeUsersPage()` is the problem..

Comment: I've used Chrome developer tools to place a break point in initializeUserPage() and the break point was not being encountered when the error was occurring.

Comment: I'm using DataTables.net control on the pages that seem to be affected.  I wonder if the DataTables control somehow interferes such the the DOM doesn't load all the way which would prevent the .ready() function from firing.  Is that a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Web Form, we normally use `pageLoad`, if we need to find a control when using with ASP.NET Ajax such as `UpdatePanel`.

However, I could not say for sure that it could solve your problem, but you could at least give a try.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[     
   function pageLoad() {
      var listBox = $find("<%= SelectedTagRadListBox.ClientID %>");
   }            
   //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: I've had to focus on other things so I haven't been able to give any of this a try just yet, but will.  Thanks for the ideas.